# How to deploy a solidity contract to the blockchain. myContract.new is not a function

Tags: contract-development, solc

I have a contract that compiles in browser solidity and solc. Using either the auto-generated deployment code in browser solidity or my own npm version, I end up with the error

> "myContract.new" is not a function.

This, as  I understood it, is a function intrinsic to the Contract type, since it's required for deployment. When I do `console.log(myContract)` I get

> [Function: bound Contract].

When I try to deploy,there is an extremely unhelpful error message / random code output as well:

```
 node_modules/solc/soljson.js:1 (function (exports, require, module,
 __filename, __dirname) { var Module;if(!Module)Module=(typeof Module!=="undefined"?Module:null)||{};var moduleOverrides={};for(var
 key i
 Module){if(Module.hasOwnProperty(key)){moduleOverrides[key]=Module[key]}}var
 ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB=typeof window==="object";var
 ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER=typeof importScripts==="function";var
 ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE=typeof process==="object"&&typeof
 require==="function"&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER;var
 ENVIRONMENT_IS_SHELL=!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER;if(ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE){if(!Module["print"])Module["print"]=function
 print(x){process["stdout"].write(x+"\n")};if(!Module["printErr"])Module["printErr"]=function
 printErr(x){process["stderr"].write(x+"\n")};var
 nodeFS=require("fs");var
 nodePath=require("path");Module["read"]=function
 read(filename,binary){filename=nodePath["normalize"](filename);var
 ret=nodeFS["readFileSync"](filename);if(!re
```

Comment: Can you rename your contract to something other than `contract` or `Contract`? Just to make sure you are not using reserved words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are using the proper version of web3 for js.

For example, `ethereum.js` appears to be outdated

So make sure your javascript script begins with:

```
var Web3 = require('web3'); 
var web3 = new Web3();
```

not

```
var web3 = require('ethereum.js');
```